# Easy way to transfer data globally in a Peer-to-Peer network using C#

Tags: c#, webrtc, p2p, hole-punching, nat-traversal

Since a few weeks I am desperately trying to create an application that can transfer data in a peer to peer network, among other things.

After trying multiple libraries (as mentioned below) I never had any success. There were either problems with the connection itself, or I could not implement NAT-Traversal or UDP Hole Punching in any way.

Which leads to my main question: Is there an easy and modern way of using C# for Peer-to-Peer communication that can be used internet-wide without port forwarding? Does anyone have any experience with that?

All I need is to transfer a byte array or string value.
I'd be very happy if someone could help me out.

I've tried several WebRTC-Libraries for C# .NET 6.0 including SIPSorcery and microsoft.mixedreality.webrtc. Also, I've tried the WebRTC NuGet-Package which isn't compatible with .NET 6.0.
Besides that, I tried some things with TcpListeners and WebSockets but I just couldn't find out how to connect peers over the internet.

Comment: The easiest way is an REST API using ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Yeah, but if you dont host the REST API on a public server you can't use it internet-wide. I need an application that's independent of any infrastructure so this solution isn't gonna work for me :/

Comment: You can use internet wide, you just need the other end IP address and that the ports you're using are open in your router and firewall.

Comment: I know, but that's the problem here. Since there is a thing called NAT, this isn't that easy.